# Keep a random row, by group in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with company data and some duplicated companies by their id. These duplications are due differences in variables like city that it is in, or sector, among other variables.

This is a simplified example of my data

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input id $ city $ sector $;
datalines;
1,A,0015
1,B,0912
1,C,0812
2,D,0712
2,E,0612
2,F,0512
3,G,0412
3,H,0312
3,I,0212
4,J,1012
4,K,5512
4,L,5515
5,M,3042
5,O,2012
5,P,3012
6,Q,6012
6,Q,8012
6,Q,4012
7,R,6012
7,S,2012
7,T,0317
8,U,0016
8,V,0014
8,W,0032
9,Y,0312
9,Z,1012
9,A,0212
;
RUN;
```

I want to have only one line per company id, but I dont want to transpose the data nor to evaluate the differences on their other variables. Instead, I want random drop duplicated rows by `id`, keeping only one random row per company id. `nodupkey` alone doesn't work for me, because it always keep the first row.

I tried to adapt a code I saw in a SAS forum but it didnt work for me:

```
data temp;
drop seed;
set have;
by id;
retain random;
if first.id then do;
  seed = input(id, 8.);
  random = ranuni(seed) ;
end;
run;

proc sort;
data=temp out=want;
by id random;

proc sort;
data=want nodupkey;
by id;
```

Comment: Don't keep changing the SEED.  That kind defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the random number generation part it should work fine.  There are some misplaced semicolons in the two sort steps you need clean up also.

```
data temp;
  set have;
  random = rand('uniform');
run;

proc sort data=temp out=want;
  by id random;
run;

proc sort data=want nodupkey;
  by id;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL to select a random row within a group.

```
proc sql;
  create table want (drop=rando) as
  select *, ranuni(1) as rando
  from have
  group by id
  having rando = min(rando)
  ;
```

If you are concerned that the random number stream could deliver two consecutive values that are duplicates (ie two or more rows `having rando=min(rando)`, the following double dow will avoid that:

```
data want(drop=_max _maxi _rand);
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    _rand = ranuni(1);
    if _rand > _max then do;
      _max = _rand;
      _maxi = _n_;
    end;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if _maxi = _n_ then output;
  end;
run;
```